# Simulation of PC Speaker in Windows 7?

Tags: winapi, audio, pcm

I was quite surprised recently to find that the Beep( ) function in the Windows API is, as of Windows 7 (and Visa x64?), rerouted to the sound card. I'm currently working on a 2D video game engine and thought that it would be a cool feature to allow for use of the PC speaker. Is there any way to programmatically call the PC Speaker in Windows 7? If not, are there any resources available that could help with the simulation of the PC Speaker through a sound card? I know DOSBOX is able to do the later...Any help is appreciated.

---Dan

Answer (score 2):

Larry Osterman, the MSFT programmer that worked on the audio sub-system since Vista blogged about the fate of the Beep driver.  His post [is here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150212032410/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx).

Comment: This is actually the article that I read earlier today which originally informed me of the rerouting scenario. I suppose, then, it would be better to focus on the later half of the question: Any ideas for simulating the PC Speaker via sound card?

Comment: Erm, just call Beep().  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hans, please read the previous posts and the article referenced.

Comment: What are you talking about?  What previous posts?  What referenced article?  Improve your question if I'm completely off the mark.

Comment: Wow. I'm sorry. I totally did not realize that you were the same person that originally replied lol...My mistake.

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to simulate the retro sound of the PC Speaker, and the revamped sound-card Beep( ) has a very different character to it.

Comment: You have to use a bandpass filter to weaken the low and high frequencies, emulating the 'tinny' response of the speaker.

Comment: Actually a sawtooth wave does a great job of emulating retro game sounds.  (It doesn't require any operations except add and maybe bitshift, which was a very useful feature in the old days when multiplication took about 20 times as long as add and division took 4 or 5 times as long as multiplication, with trig functions being just utterly ridiculous)