# How to make a PC motherboard buzzer beep in Windows 10 with a C program

Tags: c, windows

How can I make the PC bored buzzer beep in Windows 10 with a C program?

I try the fast way

```
printf("\a");
```

This outputs a sound to the device speaker, but how can I make it beep on the motherboard buzzer?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665282/simulation-of-pc-speaker-in-windows-7

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883092/how-to-make-motherboard-beep-through-c-code). From one of the answers, it appears that an OS-modification is required. I don't know of any other solution, though.

Comment: Does your motherboard have a physical buzzer? If it's a fairly new one they might have removed it.

Comment: I believe the buzzer is right next to the ISA slots.

Comment: @Lundin yes I'm sure i had one . booting PC have beep sound, phy buzzer is working fine.

Comment: Probably not possible.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/utilapiset/nf-utilapiset-beep